# Flume flow Regex error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid regex string

Tags: regex, hadoop, flume

I am getting following error whn i am trying to run flume flow for generating and loading hdfs directories based on year and month.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid regex string
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:141)
        at org.apache.flume.interceptor.RegexExtractorInterceptor$Builder.configure(RegexExtractorInterceptor.java:176)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configureInterceptors(ChannelProcessor.java:112)
        at org.apache.flume.channel.ChannelProcessor.configure(ChannelProcessor.java:82)
        at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
        at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:342)
        at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:105)
        at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:145)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

conf file for flume is:

```rb
# Purpose: load data to hdfs and partition it by year and month
# Name source, sink and channel; replicate to logger so we can see the timestamp header
agent1.sources = source2
agent1.sinks = sink-hdfs
agent1.channels = channel-hdfs
# Describe and configure the source.
agent1.sources.source2.type = spooldir
agent1.sources.source2.spoolDir = /home/hadoopuser/Task4/spooldir

agent1.sources.source2.interceptors = i2 i3 i4
agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.i2.type = regex_extractor
agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.i3.type = regex_extractor
agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.i4.type = regex_extractor
# regex to pick up the year
agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.i2.regex = (?<=\\s)[0-9]{4}(?=-)
agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.i2.serializers = y
agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.i2.serializers.y.name = year
#regex for year
#agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.ye.regex = ^[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]
#agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.ye.serializers = y1
#agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.ye.serializers.y1.name = year
# regex to pick up the month
agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.i3.regex = (?<=-)[0-9]{2}(?=-)
agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.i3.serializers = m
agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.i3.serializers.m.name = month
#regex for mointhy
#agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.mo.regex = [0-9]+
#agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.mo.serializers = m1
#agent1.sources.source2.interceptors.mo.serializers.m1.name = month

# Define the HDFS sink 2 –year and month
agent1.sinks.sink-hdfs.type = hdfs
agent1.sinks.sink-hdfs.hdfs.path = /Task4/partA_flume/%{year}/%{month}
agent1.sinks.sink-hdfs.hdfs.filePrefix = %{year}-%{month}
agent1.sinks.sink-hdfs.hdfs.fileSuffix = .txt

# Bind the source and sinks to the channels
agent1.sources.source2.channels = channel-hdfs
agent1.sinks.sink-hdfs.channel = channel-hdfs
# The channel will buffer events to file for durability. Type memory is faster but volatile.
agent1.channels.channel-hdfs.type = memory
# -- end of file
```

the data i am loading looks like:

```
5016833 1   2014-01-02  15:38:40    20719.257632    0
5016834 1   2014-01-02  15:38:50    20719.262176    0
5016835 1   2014-01-02  15:39:00    20719.26672 0
5016836 1   2014-01-02  15:39:10    20719.271264    0
```

Please help

TIA

I am trying to write a flume flow with the regex expression but its giving me error with the regex statement.

Comment: You have no interceptors defined for ye and mo, by the way

Comment: Yeah but that is commented anyways, i am getting error for i2

Comment: The error says nothing about which one has an error. It could be i4 since that's not defined with any regex. Otherwise, what have you used to verify your regex values?

Comment: i did remove i4 but i am getting strange output.

Comment: Such as? Please [edit] your question with any new changes you've made and errors they create